# Add a custom web part on web site page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a team site a a web site on my Office 365 (SharePoint Online Plan 1).
I've created a blog subsitesite on my team site.
How can I put a web part with my blog posts in a pege from public web site ?
I've tried to Save Published web part to site gallery but I can't add it to my public web site pages.

Is it possible ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add the web part to your public facing web site. I had this issue too.